# Field weight ignored on buildForm()

Tags: entities

I need to set the  $form['langcode']['#weight'] to -251.

I tried also to access the widget weight. But the position weight still remains on bottom of the form.

Why is that? I tried:

```
//form field sort ('#weight')
$form['langcode']['#weight'] = "-251";
$form['langcode']['widget']['#weight'] = "-251";
$form['langcode']['widget'][0]['#weight'] = "-251";
$form['langcode']['widget'][0]['value']['#weight'] = "-251";
$form['langcode']['#weight'] = -251;
$form['langcode']['widget']['#weight'] = -251;
$form['langcode']['widget'][0]['#weight'] = -251;
$form['langcode']['widget'][0]['value']['#weight'] = -251;
```

Also on the hook_form_alter I cannot change the weight.

Comment: Have you debugged it to know that that these are the correct ways of accessing the form field property?

Comment: Yes. To me it seemed that form_alter was overwritten afterwards. Maybe  by the Drupal UI Widget Sort View that was created for my entity to add custom fields. I changed all the other field weights to get it right. So... semi solved.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes these arrays will have a `#sorted` key that needs to be set to `FALSE` for the array to be sorted (again) and your weight changes to have an effect. Here it would be at `$form['#sorted']`.

Comment: Ah. interesting. I will give it a try next time.